# How to stop/pause slide on mouse hover on navigation using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need it to be stop/pause on mouse hover on navigation, here is link of my slider. This is navigation: change slide

Please can you guys suggest me what to do?
http://demoservers.info/js-issue/demo.html

Here is download source code link: http://demoservers.info/js-issue/js-issue.zip

Comment: Post your code here, not just in a link.

Comment: Please show your code, what you have tried and so on, so that your question is clear and self-contained.

Comment: hi, I could not post code, 
i am getting some error while pasting code, thats why i have made zip file for downloading with link.

Comment: I'm New here, so might be some formatting issue when i post code.

Comment: Can you please see my link and you can press control + U for getting code or you pls download my zip there is allfile with html and js

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because shows no effort

Answer (score 0):

**Follow these steps:**

1. You need to change your JavaScript code.

   ```
   <script>
   $("#change\\ slide").mouseover(function() { // Escape white space in jQuery Selector
       $("#carousel-example-generic").carousel("pause");
   }).mouseout(function() {
       $("#carousel-example-generic").carousel("cycle");
   });

   $("#slide2").mouseover(function() {
       $("#carousel-example-generic").carousel("pause");
   }).mouseout(function() {
       $("#carousel-example-generic").carousel("cycle");
   });

   $("#slide3").mouseover(function() {
       $("#carousel-example-generic").carousel("pause");
   }).mouseout(function() {
       $("#carousel-example-generic").carousel("cycle");
   });
   </script>
   ```
2. Plz import Jquery before Bootstrap.
3. Remove duplicate imports.